# Hw to check whether Sys.time() is less than specific time

Tags: r

I want to check whether it is a true statement  `Sys.time() >="2021-01-19 11:00:00 UTC"`, but `"2021-01-19 11:00:00 UTC"` should be also changed so that it is not a fully fixed date. Date should always equal to `Sys.date()`, but hours fixed to `"11:00:00 UTC"`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Sys.time()` has todays date and `Sys.Date()` has today's date as well you can just compare the time.

```
as.integer(format(Sys.time(), '%H')) > 11
```

This could be made a bit shorter with `lubridate::hour` :

```
lubridate::hour(Sys.time()) > 11
```